# Using Oracle DB in a C# WinForms application

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I'm working on a project written in C# and using an Oracle database. In my researches, `System.Data.OracleClient` is deprecated and Microsoft recommends a third party Oracle provider. I decided to use the ODP provider from Oracle.

My application is a DB query intensive application, and I'm writing each of the queries on my own. For example, I'm using Data Navigator and I have to write queries for adding, removing, and updating a row.

Isn't there any way i can use the advantages of ADO.NET with Oracle?

Comment: Have you looked at the entity framework or nhibernate?

Comment: As far as I could tell from 2 minutes of googling, Data Navigator works with any kind of data set, even xml data. Maybe you could post a new question with your problems connecting ODP.NET and your program?

Comment: Yes i know this but but my problem is not loading the grid, my problem is loading the collection from DB.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "loading the connection from the db"? Code would help, with explanation of what results you expected vs the results you actually saw.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's ODP.Net provider **is** an ADO.Net provider. It follows the ADO.Net contracts. What ADO.Net feature are you missing?

Comment: I'm wondering if any tool with `Visual Studio 2012` serves some kind of convenience for creating queries, filling data grids. In my case i'm doing them by hand but isn't there an automatized way?

Comment: Creating queries is more than just a convenience, but you can use the result of ODP.Net query as the data source in any grid control in pretty much the same way you would with other ADO.Net providers.

Comment: Actually i tried ODP.NET tools for visual studio. But i generates the db code inside the visual items. I already created a well structured class set for accesing db and handling the connection. I'm looking for some kind of query generator for copying and psting to my DB structure becasue i will have to write a lot of queries and it's open to mistakes if i write them on my own.(creating the query[for common queries like insert update delete etc.], inserting parameters, getting result)